# How to run a command at boot up automatically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to mount a shared folder at a boot up automatically so I don't have to manually write this line to the xterm every time:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/host
```

I have done this:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And added at the end of the file:

```
@reboot /home/richard/mounthost
```

The file /home/richard/mounthost contains:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/host
```

But it is not working. Any help?

I am using Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For mounting on boot, you should add it to `/etc/fstab`. Take a look here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 4):

The proper place to add filesystems to be mounted on boot is `/etc/fstab`. See the `fstab(5)` man page for details.

Answer (score 2):

Add a line to /etc/fstab.  This will mount the file system at startup,  The header will show you which column to place the various option.  Use `man mount` and man fstab for additional information.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here have already pointed out the proper way of specifying boot-time mounts.

So why does your script not work? Have you set execute permissions on it? e.g.

```
chmod +x /home/richard/mounthost
```

Perhaps the device is not yet ready to be mounted at the point in time when cron runs its @reboot jobs? Check the system logs for messages.

Finally, a note about system security: It is very bad policy to run scripts from the root crontab that are not owned by root! If the `richard` account is ever compromised, an intruder can gain root access by modifying `/home/richard/mounthost`. If you decide not to put your device into `/etc/fstab`, I would strongly recommend changing your crontab entry so that it runs the `mount` command directly, and does not run a non-root-owned script.

Comment: Very nice point on not running scripts from root, which are not owned by root. :)