# On Ubuntu, where is the best place to put a mount command to run on startup?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I'm trying to mount a device at /dev/sdf and I want it to be mounted for all users once the system has started. It is Ubuntu 10.04 Server.

I think the answer is something like /etc/rcS.d but I can't be certain exactly...

Many thanks,
Chris.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a command at boot up automatically?](http://serverfault.com/questions/202704/how-to-run-a-command-at-boot-up-automatically)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, if you want a filesystem to mount when your system boots you add an entry to `/etc/fstab`.   Entries in `fstab` looks something like this:

```
/dev/sda2 /home ext4 defaults  1 2
```

That's:

```
<device> <mountpoint> <filesystem_type> <options> <dump_frequency> <fsck_pass>
```

The last two fields are no longer terribly important; you can typically duplicate them from existing entries in your file.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use the file `/etc/fstab`.  It contains all the filesystems that should be mounted at boot time.  Read the man page for fstab(5) for more information, but the line you need to add should look something like this

```
# dev         mount point           fstype  fs_options   dump   fsck
/dev/sdf    /path/to/mount/point    ext4    defaults      1      2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in `/etc/fstab` where all system-wide mounts are defined.

Answer (score -2):

There is a /etc/rc.local script executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel

Comment: You should never be mounting things in the runlevel inits.